# Group Created in QGIS Disappears When QGIS is Reopened

Tags: qgis, group-layer

I have a situation where a newly created group layer (with various geometry types that are not scratch or temporary layers) disappears when re-opened. In some cases, it occurs right away, other times it is one to 2 (or more) days. When I run into this issue, I re-build the group using the shapefiles previously created.

Multiple users are accessing the same QGIS project. One user may be using a different version, not sure if this would play a role in the situation.

QGIS version is 3.22.11.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you ruled out other users overwriting your changes?

Comment: We have yes. No one has entered qgis and intentionally deleted the data.